# Recursively finding maximum sum possible in a vector with a limit

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, max, limit

So,
I have a limit, lets say 100 and
I have a vector that is filled with some numbers like 20,60,45 etc.

I need to find the maximum sum possible that is less than limit.

I have tried a couple of things but after trying too much, i just gave up so there is nothing i can show you for now.
Basically i just couldn't find the algorithm.

I tried to add more variables to the function, like `totalWeight`.

Although I'm supposed to return some `totalWeight`

```
int findOptimumLuggageWeight(int weightLimit, vector<int> collectionOfWeights)
{   
    int numberOfItems = collectionOfWeights.size();

    if (){
        
    }

    else{
        
    }
}
```

There is an example of output:

> weightLimit = 100
>
> collectionOfWeights = 40,25,20,30,44
>
> Output: 99

Comment: You could always do a brute-force approach; calculate all possible sums less than or equal to the limit, then pick the greatest one.

Comment: So you are basically asking _"Gimme teh codez plz"_??

Comment: This is basically the *knapsack problem*. Google for it in order to get the algorithms.